# Bootstrap Multiselect Search not work correctly

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm working with multiselect dropdown enableFiltering.

But something went wrong. See below:

[image]

I had an option **Hoàng Anh Hào**

When I type **Hoàng**, **Hoàng Anh Hào** option not visible. But another option contains **Hoàng** still show.

When I type **Hào** or **Anh**, **Hoàng Anh Hào** show again.

My js code:

```
$(item.selector).multiselect({
                    includeSelectAllOption: true,
                    enableFiltering: true,
                    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
                    maxHeight: 400,
                    buttonWidth: '100%',
                    onChange: function (option, checked) {
                        // do something
                    }
});
```

I'm working with asp.net so I can not put some example.

Why? May it cause of **Unikey**? How can I fix it?

Comment: can you put down your code which you tried?

Comment: @swetanshkumar Yeah, I updated my code, please see change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ to see the issue.

1. Paste:

   Hoàng Anh Hào

   Hoàng Anh Hào
2. Click convert, result show two different results :(

May that field was pasted from somewhere.

I manualy type **Hoàng Anh Hào** to update in DB and problem has gone!

[image]